# how to find column whose name contains a specific string

Tags: pandas

I have following pandas dataframe with following columns

```
 code    nozzle_no     nozzle_var    nozzle_1    nozzle_2   nozzle_3   nozzle_4
```

I want to get columns names nozzle_1,nozzle_2,nozzle_3,nozzle_4 from above dataframe

I am doing following in pandas

```
 colnames= sir_df_subset.columns[sir_df_subset.columns.str.contains(pat = 'nozzle_')]
```

But, it also includes following nozzle_no and nozzle_var, which I do not want. How to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) `regex` param here:

```
df.filter(regex='nozzle_\d+')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.str.contains` has a `regex` flag, that is True by default, so you can enter a regex:

```
colnames= sir_df_subset.columns[sir_df_subset.columns.str.contains(pat = 'nozzle_\d+$')]
```

but the answer of @anky_91 with `df.filter` is MUCH better.